# Why is it considered good practice to reject errors for common occurrences when it is not considered good practice to throw errors?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling, promise

It is easy to find opinions that consider it bad practice to use exceptions for non-exceptional events, here is an example:

> Definitely not exceptions. A failed login is hardly an "exceptional"
> case and it just a normal course of logic for the application. If you
> use an exception then you'll always have to wrap logging in with an
> exception handler for no other reason than to handle the case of a
> failed login. That seems like the very definition of using exceptions
> for logic flow, which isn't right.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22807812/1283776

It is equally easy to find opinions that consider it good practice to reject promises for non-exceptional events, here is an example:

> When you have an asynchronous operation with a promise interface, one
> would usually reject the Promise with an Error object as the reject
> reason to signify an error. That's the core design theory of promises.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56918433/1283776

Why does the general community consider it bad practice to throw errors for non-exceptional events and reject promises for the same? The reason for my confusion is that these to error passing constructs seem very similar to me. Here is how I would need to handle them in client code:

Login is synchronous and throws an error if unsuccessful:

```
try {
  login(credentials)
  // get token
} catch (err) {
  // print: unable to login
}
```

Login is asynchronous and rejects a promise if unsuccessful:

```
try {
  await login(credentials)
  // get token
} catch (err) {
  // print: unable to login
}
```

Comment: I suspect a lot of it comes from personal preference - a coherent argument could easily be made either way. I suspect the only time it's really unanimously bad practice is if you're hijacking an error path and 'assuming' you know what went wrong - that way you might be at risk of unknown unknowns.

Comment: Closely related: [Why are exceptions used for rejecting promises in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21616432/1048572)

Comment: I'd think it has a lot to do with the fact that a promise *is* a return value, very similar to a tagged enum in that it either "contains" a result or an error, and that [`.then(…, …)` can be used wonderfully for branching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). This was however before the advent of `async`/`await`, which has made rejections much more similar to exceptions.